# What's returned in a DNS query?

Tags: dns-zone

In a DNS query (any query), is just the requested record returned or is the entire zone file returned? ie, if I ping google.com in the command line, will just the A-record be returned or will the entire zone file for google.com be returned?

Comment: Two words: packet capture.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, in the standard case, only the record you ask for is returned.

Zone files can be huge and in many/most cases, complete zone transfers are not allowed anyway.

Comment: Are not allowed under what conditions? There are tutorials showing how to do a zone transfer, there must be conditions.

Comment: You can configure in your DNS who is allowed to do a zone transfer. My systems are configured to allow zone transfers only for the upstream name servers and the admin network. This is done for security reasons  as zones may include records that don't need to be public and in general, tell quite a lot about the internal network. In general, you ever only need zone transfers for debugging purposes as an admin and to get the zone to other DNS servers. Normal end users don't need them.